# Disabling non 'selected' options in multiple select elements except for one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I am trying to disable all non-selected items from multiple select elements except for one. I was trying to exclude the one select element based on its `name` attribute: `name="tloStatus"`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($("select[name!=tloStatus]")) {
        $('option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

How do I only apply this:

```
$('option:not(:selected)').attr('disabled', true);
```

to every select element but the one with `name="tloStatus"`?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because you were selecting *all* unselected `option` elements regardless of the parent `select` element's `name` attribute.

You could simplify it to the following so that only unselected `option` elements that are a *descendant* are selected:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2pa3r852/)

```
$("select[name!=tloStatus] option:not(:selected)").attr('disabled', true);
```